# Custom VSTS Extension: how to invoke dotnet tool in VSTS extension's build task script

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to create VSTS Build Task extension, that invoke following CLI command:

```
libman restore
```

Of course, the libman CLI does not have to be installed on the build agent, so I think it should also attempt to install it:

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
```

As far as I understand, in order to make this work on Linux build agents, I should use typescript, rathen that powershell.

**How to install the dotnet tool CLI (or locate otherwise) and invoke the command using typescript?**

EDIT:
I have this so far:

```
import * as path from "path";
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');

let libmanExePath = tl.which('libman');
if (!libmanExePath){
    var dotnet = tl.tool(tl.which('dotnet', true));
    await dotnet.arg(['tool', 'install', '-g', 'Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli']).exec();
}
var libman = tl.tool(libmanExePath);

await libman.arg(['restore']).exec();
```

but how do I locate the CLI tool, that is referenced using **DotNetCliToolReference** in .csproj?